# Make all bold text in a html automatically large with Python (Beautiful soup)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a simple question. Is it possible to automatically change the size of a font in a html-file if the text is in bold? I use the Beautiful Soup to process the html-file. So, what I want is the implementation of the rule "if a part of text in a html-file is bold, then make it size 18 (say)". Something like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
for tag in soup:
    ## new_soup = BeautifulSoup(str(tag).FONTSIZE_CHANGE_FUNCTION)
    tag.replace_with(new_soup)
with open(path_out, 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(str(soup))
```

Thanks in advance, 
Denis

Comment: Surely that's a matter for CSS?

Comment: Sorry, what is CSS?

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel Roseman has stated above, CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) would likely be a better way to change the size of bold text. 
CSS controls the appearance of the webpage where as the HTML contains the structure/text. 
In this simple example below, the CSS sets all bold text `b` to be `font-size` 36.

```css
b {
   font-size: 36pt;
}
```

```html
<b>This is some text that is bold</b><br/>
This is not bold text so stays the same size.
```

See https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/ for more information about CSS.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I still don't understand where in the python program I should place this code.

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your question to explain what your end goal is. Python may not be necessary. Do you control the webpage that you wish to modify, is it something you download?

Comment: My goal is to modify the html-file as I said, but it is also the part of the large process. In this process I read automatically a html-file from a link in a e-Mail, then modify it and then save it at some location. The whole process must be in python. The end goal of the whole process is that it runs in batch without the necessity for me to do anything. Actually, it works now, I have only to add this new feature about making bold text large. I hope it was clear enough. I also added some more code above.